# How Do I Name The job With Spaces In Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops

My azure-pipelines.yml file looks like this:

```
jobs:
-job: BuildDeploy
```

How do I add spaces to that? I want it to say 'Build and Deploy' but putting quotes in like this still fails:

```
jobs:
-job: 'Build and Deploy'
```